Reverse proxy for a streamlit app with apache2 under a subdirectory
I am running a streamlit app on a dedicated server on the internet. The app runs on port 8501.
I have setup a reverse proxy with apache2 to redirect the traffic to port 8501. I also have https and a certificate from letsencrypt set up. I can access the app when I go do https://example.com. Everything is working fine at this stage.
Here is the relevant part of my /etc/apache2/sites-available/
# Enable SSL
ServerName example.com
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/example.com/privkey.pem
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf

# Forward traffic to https
ServerName example.com
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{ENV:HTTPS} on
RewriteRule (.*) http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]

# password protect
<Directory "/var/www/html">
        AuthType Basic
        AuthName "Restricted Content"
        AuthUserFile /etc/apache2/.htpasswd
        Require valid-user
    </Directory>

RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
   RewriteRule /(.*) ws://localhost:8501/$1 [P]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
   RewriteRule /(.*) http://localhost:8501/$1 [P]


Now, I would like the app to be accessible through a subdirectory of the domain, e.g. domain.com/llm. So I update the apache2 conf as follows:
RewriteEngine On
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} =websocket
   RewriteRule /llm/(.*) ws://localhost:8501/$1 [P]
   RewriteCond %{HTTP:Upgrade} !=websocket
   RewriteRule /llm/(.*) http://localhost:8501/$1 [P]

ProxyRequests off
<Location /llm>
        ProxyPass http://localhost:8501/
        ProxyPassReverse /
</Location>

After restarting apache2, I fail to access mydomain.com/llm. I get the following errors in my browser dev console:
GET
https://example.com/static/media/SourceSansPro-SemiBold.abed79cd0df1827e18cf.woff2
[HTTP/2 404  145ms]


What am I doing wrong?
I expected the streamlit app to be accessible through example.com/llm with the new apache2 configuration.
